# Smooth scrolling In UICollectionView inside UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am using the UICollectionView Inside UICollectionViewCell. Top CollectionView will scroll in Veritical direction (Left <-> Right ) and Inner CollectionView will scroll in Horizontal direction(Top<->Bottom)..

When I scroll the Top collectionView Top to bottom scrolling is not smooth, because of the Inner CollectionView scrolling.

Is there any way to smoothly scroll the top CollectionView from Top<->Bottom?

Top CollectionView DataSource Method

```m
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellId";

CustomCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]

......

......

}

 - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
 retrun 10;

 }

 **Within CustomCollectionViewCell Inner CollectionView Datasource**

 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

 static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellId";

 CustomCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]

 ......

 ......

}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
retrun 10;

}
```

Comment: where is the data source for the inner collection view placed ?

Comment: maintain separate class for inner UICollectionView, complexity will reduce and can solve easily

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you are doing is wrong approach, you are using `UICollectionView` as container inside of an `UICollectionViewCell`... the Scroller cannot find to whom I have to scroll either the outer control i.e your root `UICollectionView` or the `UICollectionView` inside of your `UICollectionViewCell`. you may try some other approach if you can figure out some. or it would be good if you come up with some sample code.

Comment: You can add gesture to bottom UICollectionView.

Answer (score 0):

There will be no issues if you place the delegate and data source of the collection view inside the main collection view cell to the main collection view cell.

Like as follows:

Collection view cell interface :

```
@interface GalleryCell()
<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>
{
    NSArray *dataSourceArray;
}
@end
```

And implementation:

```
@implementation GalleryCell

            #pragma - datasources
            // Defines the number of cells in a section of collection view
            - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
            {
                return dataSourceArray.count;
            }

            // Defines the cells in the collection view
            - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
            {
                UICollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellId" forIndexPath:indexPath];
                return cell;
            }
    @end
```

Comment: I am placing the Inner collectionview delegate and datasoure method within the Main UICollectionViewCell Class..